# swiftでrealmの導入

Tags: swift, xcode

realmのデータベースを導入する為、半日cocoapodsでのrealmの導入法を調べたのですが、挫折してしまいました。。
サンプルのプロジェクトを作りXcodeを終了して、ターミナルでcocoapodsのインストールまではできたのですが、その先のpodfileを作って〜からがどのサイトを見ても理解できなく、導入ができません。
どなたか、導入法がわかる方がいましたら、どうかご教授お願いします。
よろしくお願いします。。

Comment: 実際に参考にしているサイトを追記して頂き、具体的な手順としてどこまで出来ていてどこから出来ないのかを教えて頂くことは可能ですか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。抽象的な質問申し訳ございません。解決いたしました。ですが、ご指摘ありがとうございます。これから自力で解決不可能なことが起きたらご指摘の通り、具体的な質問を心がけるようにいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問する場合は環境のバージョンなどもあればいいかと思います。
また、実行出来るコードまで全て説明すると1つの記事が書けてしまうほど長くなるので
今、詰まっているであろう`Podfile`を導入するところまで回答します。

まず、cocoapodsのインストールまで出来たとのことですが`pod setup`まで終わりましたか？
とりあえず終わっている前提でお話しします。

ターミナルからプロジェクトのディレクトリに入り、`pod init`を実行します。
正常にcocoapodsのセットアップが終わっていれば`Pods`と`Podfile`が作成されます。
もし既に`Podfile`があるのであればエラーになるので削除してください。
上記のコマンドにより作成された`Podfile`を`vim`コマンドなりテキストエディタなりで開き、
下記のように記述します。

```
target 'ProjectName' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for ProjectName(この下に必要なライブラリを記述する)
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

上記まで保存ができたらターミナルからプロジェクトディレクトリで`pod install`を実行します。
2回目以降の編集の場合などは各ライブラリを最新にする意味合いで`pod update`でも良いです。

実行が終わりましたら普段開いているであろう`ProjectName.xcodeproj`の他に
`ProjectName.xcworkspace`が出来ているかと思いますので、そちらを開きます。
あと`Realm`と`RealmSwift`をインポートしコードを記載してください。

---

上記、ターミナル操作に慣れている前提で記載しました。
不明点あれば追記しますのでコメントでおしらせください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！お教えいただいた通り操作しましたところ、導入成功いたしました！
本当にありがとうございます。